# Empty zip archive: Couldn't find template for digesting: projects/repositories/archive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab, passenger

I have gitlab-ee self-hosted on my own server (running without a license). I'm using an existing nginx/passenger installation, and so I followed the instructions found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passengernginx-installation). I'm also using Let's encrypt to generate my own certificates and I've configured nginx to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

The installation generally works well, but I recently tried to download a repository as a zip file, but the zip file is always empty. Based on another forum post, I tried installing gitlab-workhorse, but this didn't solve the problem either.

Looking at the gitlab-rails/production.log file, I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/amrbekhit/repo-name/-/archive/master/repo-name-master.zip" for XX.XX.XX.XX at 2019-09-14 14:05:27 +0300
Processing by Projects::RepositoriesController#archive as ZIP
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"amrbekhit", "project_id"=>"repo-name", "id"=>"master/repo-name-master"}
  Couldn't find template for digesting: projects/repositories/archive
```

Any thoughts as to what the problem could be?

Here is what the URL looks like:

```
https://gitlab.mysite.com/amrbekhit/repo-name/-/archive/master/hydra-takip-sistemi-master.zip
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        # HTTP to HTTPS redirect
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name gitlab.mysite.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}


server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name gitlab.mysite.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mysite.com/privkey.pem;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$ {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/builds/download {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /ci/api/v1/builds/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /api/v4/jobs/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }


  # For protocol upgrades from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 we need to provide Host header if its missing
  if ($http_host = "") {
  # use one of values defined in server_name
    set $http_host_with_default "gitlab.mysite.com";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  location @gitlab-workhorse {

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    # Do not buffer Git HTTP responses
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host_with_default;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;

    ## The following settings only work with NGINX 1.7.11 or newer
    #
    ## Pass chunked request bodies to gitlab-workhorse as-is
    # proxy_request_buffering off;
    # proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 502 /502.html;

  # Certbot
  location /.well-known {
      root /var/www/certbot;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I figured it out - I was mistakenly using the [**Using an existing Passenger/NGINX installation**](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passengernginx-installation) rather than referring to [**Using a non-bundled web-server**](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server). The setup now works just fine.